# Line intersects a side of a triangle at a trisection point and is parallel to a second side, then it intersects the third side at a trisection points?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Is true that if a line intersects a side of a triangle at one of its trisection points and is parallel to a second side, then it intersects the third side at one of its trisection points?

I'm tutoring somebody and this is one of the questions. We are supposed to reply always true or never. Can somebody tell me what a trisection point of a triangle is? And then also help me understand the truth of this claim? Thank you

Comment: Can you explain how you know this is only true for isosceles triangles?

Comment: Yes, this is Intercept Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem

Comment: @Henry I was wrong..BPT had just slipped from my mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trisection points of a side will be the two points which divide the side into thirds.

Hint: Consider the diagram below and the similar triangles:

[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! I can clearly see now that this statement is always true.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me.